# How to verify if characteristic equation is right?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am new to EigenValues and EigenVectors. I am trying to solve a basic sum and somehow I am going wrong.

The formula I know to get the characteristic equation is:
$\lambda^3 - \sum(\text{diagonal elements}) \lambda^2 +  \sum(\text{minors})\lambda- \det(A) $
Somehow, my calculations are going horribly wrong. I have no idea where I made the mistake.

The matrix is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 2 & -3 \\
 2 & 1 & -6 \\
-1 & -2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The reason I know the calculation is wrong is because I am unable to find the EigenValues via synthetic division (this is the way I am taught at college).
My characteristic equation is:  $\lambda^3 + \lambda^2 -9\lambda -45$

Will someone please tell me what is wrong ?

*I use http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=9aa01caf50c9307e9dabe159c9068c41 to verify my answer*

Comment: Note that the lines always sum to $-3$, therefore $\left(-3, \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$is an eigenpair.

Comment: @GitGud ah ? I dont know what that is. I have to do it the long way.

Comment: It's a simple fact that it is easy to prove. Note that $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a + b + c\\ d + e + f\\ g + h + i \end{bmatrix}$$so if the sums of the lines are constant, say $S$, you get $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=S\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ as required. It's a useful trick.

Comment: @GitGid will u please verify my characteristic eqn ?

Comment: It is wrong because $-3$ isn't a root of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct characteristic polynomial is $\lambda ^3+\lambda ^2-21\lambda -45$.

---

It's a simple fact that it is easy to prove. Note that $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a + b + c\\ d + e + f\\ g + h + i \end{bmatrix}$$so if the sums of the lines are constant, say $S$, you get $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=S\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ as required.

It's a useful trick that it's worth to remember. It is easily generalizable to matrices of any order.

Using this trick on your matrix yields the eigenpair $\left(-3, \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$.

---

If this doesn't work, the way to find a 'simple' root is to use the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

In this case it tell us that the rational roots (hopefully they are integers) of the polynomial, if they exist, they are in the set $\left\{\dfrac d 1\colon \mathbb Z\ni d\mid 45\right\}$ and it's easy to check that $-3$ is one such root. If you're lucky you might even find other ones before you get to $-3$.

Comment: is therr any tool / site to find charscteristic equations ? so that i can verify ??

Comment: @LittleChild [Example with Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-2+%2C2+%2C+-3%7D%2C%7B2%2C+1+%2C-6%7D%2C%7B-1+%2C+-2+%2C+0%7D%7D).